# JSON parse error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, web-services

I am using sendAsynchronousRequest request to server for getting data from it. When i check web service in browser its working fine and able to get the response. But when i sending request from Xcode i am not able to get the response in Xcode. I am using the below code for sending response.

```
NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rest_stores/storeCategoryListByStoreId/%@.json",baseurl,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"storeid"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         NSError *jsonError;
         NSData *trimmedData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:trimmedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
         if (jsonError)
         {
             NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", jsonError);
             [HUD hide:YES];
             return;
         }
}];
```

And request taking too much time for to load response and after that I am getting response data null. And the error which Xcode shows me.

```
JSON parse error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x112e4d390 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

Till Yesterday it was working fine. But When i start it today. I am facing this wired issue. I am not able to get response of any web service of my project but all are working fine in browser.

Comment: need more info. setup breakpoint before at line: `NSError *jsonError;` and tell us what you see in next variables: `response, data, error`?

Comment: Error is i mentioned here. And response and data both are nil.

Comment: if response and data are nil its mean one server not response correctly. Test REST URL API by REST any utils.

Comment: @Bimawa Thanks for your interest. I solved my problem, May be it's Xcode issue. I just remove projects from Organizer and reset simulator. Now it's working fine as it is.

Comment: Not at all, it's true, compilation see all project only once, all next compilations compilated only changes files, for save a time. And sometimes we have issue it looks like your situation. Sometime clear project before it's helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, May be it's Xcode issue. I just remove projects from Organizer and reset simulator. Now it's working fine as it is.